# mobile careers message layout not displaying correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design, mobile-web

Looking at the careers mobile site I get the following issue

[image]

Comment: Can you let me know what device and version of android your using?

Comment: Nexus 5, Android 4.4.2

Comment: @Juice I can reproduce with iPhone 4S and Safari, only mobile theme though. Full site theme is fine. Paul, removed chrome and android tags as the bug happens also in other platforms/browsers.

Comment: Must be a screen size issue cause it looks fine on my 5S?

Comment: Pfft. Nevermind. I was able to repro. Doesn't look like we do the messages as a mobile template. I'll see what we can do.

Comment: @Juice well, summon the Cavalry to assault and defeat this bug! :D

Comment: Nice to see you guys are so gung-ho on this.  Thank you

Comment: Depends on the fix as to when it will get fixed. For now you're better off using the full site to access messages.

Comment: @Juice, yeah i just noticed this too, i hope you guys can figure something out cause the stack exchange app for Android will send you to the website from an inbox notification... Kind of a jarring experience. (Nexus 4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've implemented some basic mobile styling so the messages screen is now usable.

[image]